# Why prepending file location with file: in application.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I've seen some application.yaml files where a file path is prepended with `file:` like this:

```
ssl:
  key-store: file:/etc/ssl/keystore.p12
```

What does a `file:` here stand for? I've searched Spring docs, but found only examples with `file:` (like here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files), but not the actual meaning behind this keyword.

Why not just using an absolute path like `/etc/ssl/keystore.p12` and pass it to `FileInputStream`

Comment: Because by default it will look inside the jar (aka `classpath:`) you need to tell Spring to look in the file system with `file:`.

Comment: @M.Deinum but when I use path starting with `file:` I get an error FileNotFoundException. I'm executing my jar on Win 10

Comment: If you get the file not found it isn't there. I doubt you have the `/etc/ssl` directory from the root of where you are running the application.

Comment: If you're executing on Windows 10, then `/etc/ssl/keystore.p12` is an invalid path (or at least, one that likely doesn't exist). File paths on Windows - generally - start with a drive letter (e.g. `C:`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this is just a dummy example. I'm using a real file and the filepath is correct. When I set path as an absolute path everyting is ok, but when I add file: then there's an error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:C:\test\test.json (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

Comment: @LicieSteinitz That error suggests you're using the `file:` prefix for something that doesn't support the `file:` prefix, but instead simply requires a file path. Context matters, this isn't some generic feature, but something that requires explicit support in the configuration class or the user(s)/consumer(s) of that configuration class.